# Can connect to port 53 but nslookup fails

Tags: networking, dns, nslookup

Trying to get my DNS back up and running after my server was shut down for a week. My issue is that I can ping / telnet port 53 fine from the outside world, and I can nslookup fine from inside the network, but I can't nslookup from outside.

Nslookup from inside network:

```
> nslookup ve4edj.ca 192.168.1.50
Server:     192.168.1.50
Address:    192.168.1.50#53

Name:   ve4edj.ca
Address: 24.77.125.34
```

Telnet from outside world:

```
> telnet 24.77.125.34 53
Trying 24.77.125.34...
Connected to 24.77.125.34.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

Nslookup from outside world:

```
> nslookup ve4edj.ca 24.77.125.34
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Is the host also reachable over UDP port 53?

Comment: This appears to be a combination of multiple issues. First and foremost, UDP is not going through. DNS by default uses UDP. DNS resolvers may not even fall back to TCP. Next, the server sucks. It needs do be `dig`ged using `+noedns`. It will return a correct response using `dig ve4edj.ca @24.77.125.34 +tcp +noedns`.

Comment: @DanielB can you elaborate as to why the server sucks? It's running 2008R2 so that I can run SolidWorks and other Windows programs via remote desktop - what can I do to make it not suck?

Comment: @DanielB I tried an online port checker that said UDP was in fact open

Comment: UDP has a different state machine from TCP. You cannot reliably ascertain a port is open unless the service that is listening responds. [It does not respond.](https://pastebin.com/npafhzBf) // It sucks because I have to use special options to not make the request fail. This isn’t proper DNS server behavior. // Are you sure your port forwarding is set up properly?

Comment: Okay, I'll start digging to see what is blocking it. It's open in the router so I'm assuming the firewall on the server is likely the culprit.

Comment: Aha! The UDP port was disabled in the server's firewall - it was definitely enabled last week so that's a strange one. Resolution is now working normally. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness sake, as an answer.

I can connect using TCP:

```
[root@server ~]# dig ve4edj.ca @24.77.125.34 +noedns +tcp

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1 <<>> ve4edj.ca @24.77.125.34 +noedns +tcp
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32111
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ve4edj.ca.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ve4edj.ca.              3600    IN      A       24.77.125.34

;; Query time: 234 msec
;; SERVER: 24.77.125.34#53(24.77.125.34)
;; WHEN: Tue May 23 20:39:24 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Nmap reports port 53 UDP as open/filtered (AKA not responding):

```
[root@server ~]# nmap -p53 -sU -sT -sV 24.77.125.34

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-23 20:35 CEST
Nmap scan report for S01063cce738ef858.wp.shawcable.net (24.77.125.34)
Host is up (0.24s latency).
PORT   STATE         SERVICE VERSION
53/tcp open          domain  Microsoft DNS 6.1.7601
53/udp open|filtered domain
Service Info: OS: Windows; CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 103.28 seconds
```

A `tcpdump` analysis further confirms that no responses are received when using UDP.

**This means something (like a firewall) along the way isn’t letting the UDP traffic through.** Since it’s probably a setup with port forwarding, you might want to take a look at that.

DNS queries are by default sent using UDP. Furthermore, DNS resolvers may not fall back to using TCP.